# want to read property of object using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I've been trying to read this object that was read from ajax get request but it's not working, and I don't know why... can anyone help me?
I've also try to append it to html but it's not reading any value at all.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: `${siteRootUrl}api/order`,
            // datatype: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function (res) {
    
                result = res;
                alert(result);
        
                 $.each(result, function(key,element){
                     alert(key , element)               
                 })
                    result.forEach(function (result) {
                    $('#a').append("<tr><td>" + result.text + "</td></tr>");
                 });
            },
            error: function (res) {
                alert('No Data');
            }
        });
    });
```

my object

```
[HttpGet]
      public string Get()
      {
           var myData = new
        {
            Host = @"sftp.myhost.gr",
            UserName = "my_username",
            Password = "my_password",
            SourceDir = "/export/zip/mypath/",
            FileName = 1
        };
       var bigCities = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "New York",
                        "London",
                        "Mumbai",
                        "Chicago"                    
                    };
                    // string.Join(", ", bigCities)
        return myData.ToString();
      }
```

Comment: Change `alert(result);` to `console.log(result)`, look in the console and tell us what you get.

Comment: this is what the console display   { Host = sftp.myhost.gr, UserName = my_username, Password = my_password, SourceDir = /export/zip/mypath/, FileName = 1 }

Comment: Is that a string or an object?  It's unclear from that object/json where you got `result.text` - there's no `"text" property.  What do you get if you change the above console.log to `console.log(result.Host)` - either the error or the host?   Did you $.each/alert work?  If it *is* an object (not json) then `result.forEach` makes no sense as you don't have an array/IList of objects...

Comment: result.Host is undefined, and yes it's not an array or list of object so that's why it doesn't work? I'm sorry I'm not very good at programming still confuse about some of the concept.

Comment: Still unclear if you have json (string) or an object - what about `console.log(result.length)`.   A value or undefined?

Comment: result.length give value of 120

Comment: Then you have a **string** - and given the format you provided earlier, it's *not* JSON as that would be `{ "Host" = "...", ..}` - ie not 120 length.    You need to export as JSON, not `return myData.ToString()`

Comment: Hello is there anything else that I can assit you on this?

Comment: Thank you , but it's alright I've already solve most of the problem I encountered. Thank everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I've been trying to read this object that was read from ajax get
> request but it's not working, and I don't know why... can anyone help
> me? I've also try to append it to html but it's not reading any value
> at all.

Well, let's start from how to nail it towards the way to investigate. Once you would know how to split the `javascript/Jquery` issue life would be easier.

**Check your response in client or Browser:**

As you have only return below object:

```
var myData = new
        {
            Host = @"sftp.myhost.gr",
            UserName = "my_username",
            Password = "my_password",
            SourceDir = "/export/zip/mypath/",
            FileName = 1
        };
```

So in browser or client site we should expect this object as output. Let's see if we got that.

[image]

**Note:** As we can see the response, data has been returned as expected. Now we need to bind it with `HTML` or more specifically in `Table` or anything else.

**Bind The Response in HTML:**

Before starting, I want to point one thing very specifically abou the `data-structure` You are returning `single string object` but searching that in `loop` that is   `$.each(result` which is not correct.

As its a single object you can directly read from the `res`. I  did the same. See the example below:

```
<div class="col-md-2 form-group">
    <button id="btnGetBackendData" class="btn btn-danger">Get Data</button>
</div>
<table class="table table-primary table-bordered mb-0" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <thead class="thead-primary">
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center">Host</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">UserName</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">Password</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">SourceDir</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">FileName</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="bindTableGetBackendData">
    </tbody>
</table>
@section scripts {
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#btnGetBackendData").click(function(e) {
               $('#bindTableGetBackendData').empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "http://localhost:5094/Controller/GetBackendData",
                        success: function(response) {
                            $('#bindTableGetBackendData').append(
                                    '<tr>'+
                                    '<td>' + response.host + '</td>'+
                                    '<td>' + response.userName +'</td>'+
                                    '<td>' + response.password + '</td>'+
                                    '<td>' + response.sourceDir + '</td>'+
                                    '<td>' + response.fileName + '</td>'+
                                   
                                    '</tr>'
                                    );

                        },
                        error: function(response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });

        });
    });
</script>
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Controller:**

I preferably written the controller as below however, you can continue yours one. I like this way:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetBackendData()
        {
            var myData = new
            {
                Host = @"sftp.myhost.gr",
                UserName = "my_username",
                Password = "my_password",
                SourceDir = "/export/zip/mypath/",
                FileName = 1
            };
           
            return Ok(myData);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the response is that string or a json object
If the response is not json we need to convert string to json

`JSON.parse`
Change this line to

```
 result = JSON.parse(res);
            console.log(result);
```

$.each/foreach will work not work if the value is not JSON

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: "a json object" *or* "a string" - json is and is only a string.  You can't "convert a string to json" as json is a string.   You mean a javascript object.